# numpy curvefit reciprocal function

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I have hardly any experience with numpy curve fitting. I can get curve fits and formulas of polynomials with degree 0 and upwards with *`np.polyfit()`*, but I seem to need a reciprocal fit of the form 1/x for this dataset and I do not know how to obtain it. It concerns this tiny dataset:

```
M = np.array([int(x) for x in range(0,11)])
R = np.array([28*24,9*24+8,5*24+14,96,3*24+2,2*24+13,51,44,39,35,32])
```

Comment: Have you looked into `scipy`? Specifically: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it might be of some use, I got an OK fit for an X-shifted power equation "R = a * numpy.power((M-b), c)" with parameters a = 3.3867896329655980E+02, b = -5.0677344974815763E-01, and c = -1.0081095967950331E+00 yielding RMSE = 0.2558 and R-squared = 0.999997
[image: plot]

Comment: Did you use scipy? How did you arrive here?

Comment: To answer your question, I used the "function finder" on my open source Python online curve fitting web site zunzun.com to look for simple functions to fit the data and this equation looked like an excellent candidate. I then fit the data at the site using http://zunzun.com/Equation/2/Power/X%20Shifted%20Power/

Comment: I would like to mention that parameter "c" is almost equal to -1, showing that your thought on the shape of best fit equation is correct. On the web site link I provided, you can make parameter "c" constant at -1 and the fit is very, very close to the results I posted.

Comment: Yes it is definitely -1 and b equals -0.5. The formula makes sense, as does the value for a. The data for some reasons is not exact. I have not yet looked into your function finder, but I will certainly will. Great stuff.